# Trying to convert DateTime into int

Tags: c#, datetime, if-statement, integer

so i have been trying to use both date time and int in the same if statement.
my code is like this:

```
public int wantedHours, wantedMinutes;
public int sysHour = System.DateTime.Now.Hour;
public int sysMinutes = System.DateTime.Now.Minute;

void Update()
{
    if (sysHour == wantedHours && sysMinutes == sysMinutes)
    {
        sendTheNotif == true;
    } else
    {
        sendTheNotif == false;
    }
}
```

but it doesnt work. unity is giving me this error:

```
error CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement
```

Comment: You can shorten this to just `sendTheNotif = (sysHour == wantedHours && sysMinutes == sysMinutes);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integers are set correctly.
You're using the equality operator in your if statements which is throwing the error
Suggest reading the [microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/equality-operators)

Try this

(note, you are checking equality between sysMinutes == sysMinutes in your if statement, is that what you're wanting to do?)

```
public int wantedHours, wantedMinutes;
public int sysHour = System.DateTime.Now.Hour;
public int sysMinutes = System.DateTime.Now.Minute;

void Update()
{
    if (sysHour == wantedHours && sysMinutes == sysMinutes)
    {
        sendTheNotif = true;
    } else
    {
        sendTheNotif = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you did not assign a value to wantedHours, and wantedMinutes.
also sysMinutes will always equal sysMinutes if there is no option to change its value in your code before comparison.

```
if (sysHour == wantedHours && sysMinutes == sysMinutes)
```

is the major problem. When you are comparing variables with == it means it should evaluate true if it is equal in type and value.
So wantedHours has no value assigned according to your code block above.
And sysMinutes is always equal to sysMinutes.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use wantedTime instead

```
var sysTime = System.DateTime.Now;

If( (int)wantedTime.Subtract(sysTime).TotalMinutes ==0)  sendTheNotif = true;
else sendTheNotif = false;
```